# Midway vs middle ; for vs through

Tags: grammaticality

> Our car broke down in the **midway** and we had to walk for the rest of the trip.

Vs

> Our car broke down in the **middle** and we had to walk through the rest of the trip.

Which one of the above sentence is more correct grammatically ?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "broke down in the middle"?  The middle of what?  Do you mean the car broke in its middle, or the car broke down in the middle of the road, or something?

Comment: "The Midway" would be a place name, such as [a part in a fair or circus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midway_(fair)).  It's also the names of many cities, buildings, and one famous US naval aircraft carrier from WWII.  You're thinking *midway*, as an adverb, without "the".  *Our car broke down **midway** through the trip*

Comment: Middle of the journey

Comment: Remove ***in the*** from the first example. Note that in your specific context it would be more "natural" to say *Our car broke down **mid-trip** and we had to walk the rest of the way*, even though I very much doubt you'd find ***mid-trip*** in any dictionaries (in such contexts, ***mid-*** is a "productive" prefix, which can be used to form new terms as and when required).

Comment: I think you can also say: our car broke down halfway through the trip

Answer (score 0):

Both examples could be correct, but need to indicate in the middle of what.

> Our car broke down **at the midway point of our trip** and we had to
>   walk the rest of the way.

This is a bit unnatural, I don't think many North American native English speakers would say it this way.

> Our car broke down in the **middle of our trip** and we had to walk the rest of the way.

This is a more natural way to say it.

@FumbleFingers has a good comment too.

Answer (score 0):

"in the midway" is never correct.

But this sounds fine:

> Our car broke down midway and we had to walk for the rest of the trip.

although this is better:

> Our car broke down midway and we had to walk the rest of the way.

This could be ok with a bit of context:

> First we had to cross a forest on a very bumpy road. Our car broke down in the middle and we had to walk through the rest of the trip.

"In the middle" works much better with a physical object (like a forest, a road) than just the trip itself.